# React JS - React Router - Render content separately

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to render content in an element separate to the menu nav element, but it keeps rendering in the same element as the menu bar. I tried to separate the links from the router but then got errors.

Here is my Router component, which I am importing into my entry file:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home.jsx';
import About from './About.jsx';
import BlogList from './BlogList.jsx';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
            </ul>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route path="/blog" component={BlogList} />
        </div>
    </Router>
)

export default Routes;

ReactDOM.render((
  <Routes />
), document.getElementById('main-nav'))
```

My question is:

How do render the content from the Home, About and Blog components in a seperate element so they don't render inside "#main-nav"? A route can only have 1 child element.

If I try to add the routes in their own div container I get errors. If I wrap a nav element to the ul, I get an error.

Ideally, I want something like this:

```html
<nav id="main-nav">
    <div>
        <ul>
          <li a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li a href="/about">About</a></li>
          <li a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="content">
    Home / ABout / Blog Content in here
</div>
```

Comment: An answer for number two: because React Router uses the path to match URLs to render the component. That means `/` matches every single URL in your app. Use the `exact` prop to only match the root path.

Comment: That makes sense I will update my code. Thank you

Comment: Also, are you attempting to make a navbar on every route?

Comment: I just want a menu to display at all times. Not sure what the best way to go about it is, as I'm new to React. Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: I see. So you want your app to have a topbar with all the links at all times in all the routes?

Comment: Yeah, exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Try wrapping your Routes in a `<Switch>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and I fixed it spliting the HTML5 into subcomponents. Basically, you just need put all your components inside the [`<BrowserRouter>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) or into [`<StaticRouter>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/StaticRouter) .For example into the `render()` try something like this:

```
        import { Router, Route, Link,NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
        import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
        import HeaderNav from './HeaderNav';
        import SectionContent from './SectionContent'; 
        import FooterComponent from './FooterComponent';    

        export default class Layout extends React.Component{
             constructor(props) {
                 super(props); 
             }
             render(){
                 var history=createBrowserHistory();
                 return(
                    <Router history={history}>
                       <HeaderNav/>
                       <SectionContent/>
                       <FooterComponent/>
                   </Router>
               ); 
           }
        }
```

Obviusly you also need the [`<NavLink>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) for the `<nav>` into the HeaderNav component and for the content you just need [`<Route>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) ,also you need [history npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history)

Comment: Thanks, this was quite a while ago I asked, but this is exactly how I'm doing it now so I will mark as accepted answer.